# How to use html/unicode symbols as marker-symbols in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts has support for png images to be used as marker symbols... How about using html/unicode symbols like: &#x21d5 / U+21D5

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-symbols/)

I tried

```
marker: {symbol: {useHTML: &#x21d5} }
```

etc. to no avail.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the highcharts you can use marker like image / base64 / defined SVG own custom shape or build-in symbols.

Docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.symbol

I suggest to post your suggestion in our uservoice [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com)